How Should I Do the Inductive Case of this Proof on Ordinals?
Question
Prove that for all ordinals $\alpha$, $V_\alpha=\{x:\rho (x)<\alpha\}$.
Note:
The function $\rho$ is a rank function.
Attempt
I did the proof by induction on ordinals. I started with the base case, followed by the inductive case, and then the limit case. However, I have a lot of issues with the inductive case.
The inductive hypothesis is $V_\alpha=\{x:\rho (x)<\alpha\}$. I want to prove this holds for $V_{\alpha + 1}$. We know that $V_{\alpha + 1}=\mathcal{P} (V_\alpha)$. However, I don’t know how to make my case.
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

How big can the rank be of a set whose elements all have rank $<\alpha$? (And why does every set in $V_{\alpha+1}$ have this property?)

@spaceisdarkgreen Can I say this: Every set that is a subset of $V_\alpha$ has a rank $\leq \alpha$. Since $x\subseteq V_\alpha$, then $x\in \mathcal{P} (V_{\alpha })$. Hence, $x$ has a rank less than or equal to $\alpha +1$. Also, is it correct to say “every set whose rank is less than $\alpha$ is a subset of $V_\alpha$”?

You can say every subset of $V_\alpha$ has rank $\le\alpha$, but that’s just saying what you’re supposed to be proving. (You need to actually use the definition of rank somewhere….)

@spaceisdarkgreen Yes. However, we are dealing with the inductive hypothesis here. Maybe I shouldn’t use the word “every”. Maybe I should say, “let $x\subseteq V_\alpha$. Then, the elements of $x$ has a rank $\leq \alpha$. Now, $x\in \mathcal{P} (V_\alpha)=V_{\alpha +1}$. Since $\alpha <\alpha +1$, then every element of $x$ has a rank less than $\alpha +1$. That is, $V_{\alpha +1}={x:\rho (x)<\alpha +1}$.

No, that doesn't make sense... you still haven't used the definition of rank at all. The inductive hypthesis tells you something stronger, namely that if $x\subseteq V_\alpha,$ or equivalently if $x\in V_{\alpha+1},$ then the elements of $x$ all have rank strictly less than $\alpha.$

@spaceisdarkgreen I have been on this for some time now. I wouldn’t mind if you give me a sketch of the proof. I will flesh it up. Up until now, I seem to be going round in circle.

(1) Show that the defintion of $\rho$ by $\in$-recursion implies that $\rho(x)\le \alpha \iff \forall y\in x; \rho(y)< \alpha.$ (2) The induction hypothesis says $V_\alpha = {x: \rho(x) < \alpha}.$ Assuming this, show that since $V_{\alpha+1} = P(V_\alpha),$ we have $V_{\alpha+1} = {x: \forall y\in x ; \rho(y) < \alpha}.$ 3) combine (1) and (2) to get $V_{\alpha+1} = {x: \rho(x) \le \alpha}$ and you're done with the successor step of the induction.
